# Retrieving consecutive rows (and the counts) with the same values

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I've got a table with almost 10 million views and would to run this query on the latest million or hundred thousand or so.

Here's a SQL fiddle with example data and input/output: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340a41

Is this even possible?

```
CREATE TABLE object (`id` int, `name` varchar(7), `value` int);

INSERT INTO object (`id`, `name`, `value`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a', 1),
    (2, 'b', 2),
    (3, 'c', 100),
    (4, 'a', 1),
    (5, 'b', 2),
    (6, 'c', 200),
    (7, 'a', 2),
    (8, 'b', 2),
    (9, 'c', 300),
    (10, 'a', 2),
    (11, 'b', 2),
    (12, 'a', 2),
    (13, 'b', 2),
    (14, 'c', 400)
;

-- Want:
-- name, max(id), count(id)
-- 'a', 4, 2
-- 'b', 14, 5
-- 'a', 12, 3
```

Comment: Your code and your sql fiddle appear to be mysql. However, your question is tagged as sql server. Which DBMS are you actually using? And regardless you need to explain your output. How is 4 the max ID for a? What about 7, 10 and 11??? And how do you get a count of 4? There are 5 rows with a and the name. Your output makes no sense to me based on the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the latest and the id is implemented sequentially, then you can do this using `limit` or `top`.  In SQL Server:

```
select top 100000 o.*
from object o
order by id desc;
```

In MySQL, you would use `limit`:

```
select o.*
from object o
order by id desc
limit 100000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, count(id) cnt, max(id) max_id, max(value) max_v
from
(select 
top 1000000  -- MS SQL Server
id,name,value 
from myTable
limit 1000000 --mySQL
order by id desc)
group by name
```

remove line which doesn't match your server.